# Bar Chart Renders Before Receiving Updated Data

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a simple issue relating to function sequence that I'm struggling to solve on my own. Essentially, I'm rendering a bar chart based on parameters selected by the user. This works perfectly on the first go, but when the user updates their parameter selection and hits "render" again, the chart doesn't update. It's only on the **second button click** that the chart renders with updated data.

I can see in the console that the "generate chart" function IS receiving the updated data, so I know the issue is that the chart is rendering before the new data is loaded. I understand that the common solution to this type of problem would be using JS Promises or callbacks, but I can't figure out how to execute it, and would really appreciate some help.

Here's the code structure. I have to make two API calls to get the data.

```
const ajaxCallOne = () => {
    // Make API call for first data set (data1). On success, invoke the next API call, passing data1.
    success: (data1) => {
        ajaxCallTwo(data1);
    }
}

const ajaxCallTwo = (data1) => {
    // Make second API call for another set of data ('data2'). On success, invoke a function to visualize all the data in a bar chart, passing it both data1 and data2.
    success: (data2) => {
        populateBarChart(data1, data2)
    }
}

const populateBarChart = (data1, data2) => {
    // Function to create a bar chart and populate it with data1 and data2 from the API calls

    // The data retrieved from the API calls is based on parameters selected by the user. When the user selects new parameters and hits the "view results" button again, we kick off another round of API calls, which pass the new data to this populateBarChart function.

    // I am using ApexCharts.js library to render the bar chart. The syntax for actually rendering the chart looks like this:
    let chart = new ApexCharts(
      document.querySelector("#audience-reach-chart-container"),
      options
    );

    chart.render();
}
```

At first I thought I needed to destroy / empty out the chart at the beginning of the function, but since the function creates a new instance of the chart every time it's invoked, there's nothing to target and destroy.

Also, when I console.log the data being received by the `populateBarChart` function, I can see the updated data is being received. So the issue must be that the chart is rendering based on the old data, and I need to control the sequence of events?

I can't figure out how to go about this within the code design. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this will be hard to answer unless you give us more JS code. Also, if you think it is relevant, could you show us some HTML? And a link to the ApexCharts.js library documentation wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right that this can be solved using callbacks, promises and even async/await.

However, this problem statement may have a nuance e.g. if you're using `<select>` dropdowns, the event listener registered on them could be slightly incorrect. OR, if the ApexCharts library's behavior is to withhold rendering for some reason, then it'll be hard to say so without going through the documentation. Hence, an example on codesandbox or jsfiddle can help us.

Let's look at one possible solution - Ideally, when using promises, we should do something like this:

```
let container = document.querySelector("#audience-reach-chart-container");

const ajaxCallOne = () => {
    // Make API call for first data set (data1).
    // No need to invoke the next API call. Just ensure it returns a promise object
}

const ajaxCallTwo = () => {
    // Make second API call for another set of data ('data2').
    // Sit still! No need to do anything here as long as this function returns a promise
}

// Run this when the user hits 'render' button
Promise.all([ajaxCallOne, ajaxCallTwo]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
  // values[0] holds data1
  // values[1] holds data2
  let options = doSomethingOnThese(values[0], values[1]);

  // Populate the BarChart here
  let chart = new ApexCharts(container, options);
  chart.render();
});
```

I've created a sample app(https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-cookies-tbcerp?file=/src/index.js) to mimic your usecase here:

```
// https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-cookies-tbcerp?file=/src/index.js
(async function () {
  var options = {
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: "bar"
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [],
    title: {
      text: "Ajax Example"
    },
    noData: {
      text: "Loading..."
    }
  };

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

  chart.render();
  try {
    const ajaxCallOne = await fetch(
      "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/yearly"
    );

    const ajaxCallTwo = await fetch(
      "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/yearly2"
    );
    let data1 = await ajaxCallOne.json();
    let data2 = await ajaxCallTwo.json();
    console.log(data1, data2);
    chart.updateSeries([
      {
        name: "Sales",
        data: data1
      },
      {
        name: "Sales2",
        data: data2
      }
    ]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: This is SO helpful, thank you! I'm attempting to implement this now and will report back. I was also able to find this a few minutes ago, but haven't gotten very far with it yet. It seems to be suggesting that I should render a blank chart first, then make the API call and update the chart with the data.
https://apexcharts.com/docs/update-charts-from-json-api-ajax/

Comment: What should I be seeing when I run `console.log(values)`? Or rather, what would I be doing with them? The `options` variable that gets passed to ApexCharts is meant to contain the returned data from the API calls.

Comment: You can refer the `console` output in this example to understand what to expect in the `values` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#try_it

Comment: `values[0]` holds `data1` and `values[1]` holds `data2`

Comment: Ok thanks I think I'm getting somewhere. When you say the API calls need to return a promise object, is this the correct syntax `Promise.resolve(value);` ? Do I put that in the success method of the Ajax call?

Comment: I've created a codesandbox for you - https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-cookies-tbcerp?file=/src/index.js , I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your time - very helpful. I think I discovered the problem. I am using a stacked bar chart and dynamically updating the values for the X-axis. The `updateSeries` function that ApexCharts provides allows me to update data that populates the chart, but not the x-axis values. See their docs for the chart i'm using -- check out the X-axis field, note how I can't access that from the `updateSeries` function. Unless I'm missing something? https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/stacked/

Comment: Sorry for not including this in original post, still in the learning process!

Comment: You can try `updateOptions` if you want to update values or other config options -  https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateOptions

Comment: Incredible thanks. I just spent a while exploring `updateSeries` and `updateOptions`. It could work but would require entirely refactoring my code and using a different code design than what I'm employing on the rest of the page. I posted the question, as it stands at this point, on the Apex github forums if you're curious: https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/discussions/3101